# How do I iterate over objects in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I am just starting out with typescript in a vue project and am running into an error trying to iterate over an object:

`Type 'Test' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator. ts(2488)`

Here's an example to reproduce it:

```js
declare interface Test {
  x: number,
  y: number
}

const test: Test = { x: 1, y: 2 }
for (const [k, v] of test) {}  // getting an error here
```

Here's the relevant bits of my tsconfig.json:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    ...
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  }
  ...
}
```

---

It seems to me like typescript would have enough context here to infer type information. Is this a thing I should be able to do; e.g. perhaps have I misconfigured typescript somehow? Otherwise are there any suggestions on how to properly iterate over an object in typescript?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Objects cannot be iterated over like that in JS either, and TS compiles to JS:

```js
const test = { x: 1, y: 2 }
for (const [k, v] of test) {}  // getting an error here
```

Use `Object.entries` instead:

```
declare interface Test {
  x: number,
  y: number
}

const test: Test = { x: 1, y: 2 }
for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(test)) {
  // do stuff with k and v
}
```